# Is the device-ID necessary?

Tags: android, admob

The official tutorial tells me this:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .addTestDevice(Parameters.deviceid)
                    .build();

            rl.addView(adView);

            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I talked with a guy from admob, he told me, that it wouldn't be necessary to get the device ID (this needs an extra permission and I try to avoid such things).

My app is online since about a month now and I have around 180 impressions. I don't got a single click from other people, altough I placed my ad in an extra menu ("Support me"). So users who go into this menu will normally have the idea to show some support I thought.

I'm not sure, but can it be, that the device-ID is really necessary to earn money?

Answer (score 1):

It just makes it so that ads are not served to your test device. It's technically a violation of the TOS if you click on the ads yourself, so that's why it's there, but it is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Device Id's are used in differentiating test devices and other devices. It is not necessary to set your device ID. In that case you will see real ads in your device instead of place holders.

About earning money using admob: Impressions are not going to earn you money,  clicks on your ads do. Different countries have different CPC (Cost Per Click) and the amount you earn per click also depends how further has the user gone into by clicking that particular ad. If he buys stuffs, download apps advertised on that ad, you will get high CPC for that particular click.